# How can I achieve a searchable data structure in VB.NET/WinForms? (Core 3.1)

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Sorry for my bad explaination in advance.

So I have the following situation: I got a forms app I am creating. I am pretty new to vb.net, but worked to some degree with Excel VBA.

I want to have a dropdown field with a list of countries, all tied to a number which can appear multiple times, for ex.

```
Germany -> 1
Netherlands -> 2
Belgium -> 2
```

Now, based on the selection of the user of this planned form I want to get the corresponding Number to calculate/use further on.

First question: How can I store the data the best, and how do I get the right number when processing?

Comment: Your question isn’t really that clear,  what part of this exactly do you have the problem with?  When you say “store the data”. What exactly are you meaning? Some sort of data base?

Comment: @Hursey I got an Excel sheet with two Colums, 1 containing the country and one containing a corresponding number. Now i need to create a combobox with these columns (2d Array??)... But I cannot seem to find out how to do it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably use a `Dictionary(Of String, Integer)`. The country names are the keys and the numbers are the values. You can even bind it to a `ComboBox` and display the keys, then get the corresponding value from the `SelectedValue` property.

Comment: This sounds very promising and seems to me that it is exaxtly what i am looking for.

Comment: Edit: Also, what is pretty neat, is the fact that you can use the Tvalue property to define multiple properties if needed.